# Un-Pickling plot gives AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'stale_callback'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle

I pickled matplotlib plot

```py
with open(save_to, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(fig, file)
```

and try to unpickle it as

```py
with open(save_to,'rb') as fid:
    ax = pickle.load(fid)
    plt.show()
```

or

```py
with open(save_to,'rb') as fid:
    ax = pickle.load(fid)
    ax.show()
```

But I get error

```py
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'stale_callback'
```

What is the reason?

The code is taken from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

where instead of plt.show() I pickle it.

thanks!

Comment: You may want to report your matplotlib version, maybe the one you're using has a bug in it. Also please provide a full runnable code (see [mcve]).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest referenced code

Comment: Sorry, I cannot test with some sklearn stuff. You may try to reduce it to a [mcve].